# How do I update text while JavaScript is running?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to make a JavaScript program that simulates the game Cookie Clicker in order to calculate an optimal strategy to reach a goal as fast as possible. Essentially how it works is by the user inputting a few things through a simple website, then using a while loop to repeat through a set of functions until it has reached a goal. This program can take a while to run and I would like to display various statistics that constantly update as the program is running, but I don't know how to do this.

As an example I've made a simple calculator that shows essentially the same issue that I am having:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Summation Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Summation Calculator</h1>
    <p>Calculates the sum of every number from 1 to your number.</p>
    <label for="number">Number:</label>
    <input type="number" id="number" min="0" value="1000000" step="10"><br>
    <button id="calculate" onclick="sum(number.value)">Calculate</button><br>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
function sum (maxNum){
    number = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= maxNum; i++){
        number += i;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Total: " + number;
    }
}
```

I have tried using `setTimeout`  and `setInterval`, but I don't really know what I'm doing and neither worked.

I made another post earlier about this, but I decided to repost because the other post didn't have any sort of example or anything. There was also another post that I looked at that had a similar problem ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025086/update-html-text-box-while-javascript-is-running)) but I couldn't really modify the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Some Important Keypoints

- We use setTimeout to run the chunk function after 0 ms.
- This does not run the function right away, but puts it in a queue.
- The queue is called the event loop and it handles async events.
- The event loop runs the tasks in the queue one by one when it can.
- It also updates and renders the HTML elements on the page.
- Using setTimeout lets the browser show the output div before the next chunk.
- If we don't use setTimeout, our code will freeze the page until it's done.

### Lets use the supreme power of setTimeout

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Summation Calculator</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Summation Calculator</h1>
        <p>Calculates the sum of every number from 1 to your number.</p>
        <label for="number">Number:</label>
        <input
            type="number"
            id="number"
            min="0"
            value="1000000"
            step="10"
        /><br />
        <button id="calculate" onclick="sum(number.value)">Calculate</button
        ><br />
        <div id="output"></div>
    </body>
    <script>
        function sum(maxNum) {
            var number = 0; // use var to declare variables
            var i = 1; // use var to declare variables
            function chunk() {
                // define a function for each chunk of work
                var count = 0; // keep track of how many iterations in this chunk
                while (count < 1000 && i <= maxNum) {
                    // limit the chunk size to 1000 iterations or maxNum
                    number += i; // add i to the sum
                    i++; // increment i
                    count++; // increment count
                }
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =
                    "Total: " + number; // update the output div
                if (i <= maxNum) {
                    // if there is more work to do
                    setTimeout(chunk, 0); // schedule the next chunk with zero delay
                }
            }
            chunk(); // start the first chunk
        }
    </script>
</html>
```